# Fetching a response using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Good day how can I fetch this ajax response using jquery? This is my current jquery code

```
    function fetch(select){
        if ($(select).val() !== null) {
            var rank= $("#rank");
            $.getJSON('{{route("json_style_rank")}}', {id: $(select).val()}, function(data) {
                $("#rank option").remove();
                $.each(data.ranks, function(){
                    rank.append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
                });
                rank.select2().val(null).trigger('change');
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is the ajax response

```
[,…]
0:{id: 118, organization_id: 6035, school_id: null, picture: "", name: "Hapkido", description: "Kicks",…}
created_at:"2017-05-22 15:34:32"
description:"Kicks"
id:118
name:"Hapkido"
organization_id:6035
picture:""
ranks:[,…]
0:{id: 561, style_id: 118, level: 1, name: "1st Dan ", type: "solid", tip_enabled: 0, tip_sequential: 1,…}
1:{id: 562, style_id: 118, level: 2, name: "1st Gup", type: "double", tip_enabled: 1, tip_sequential: 1,…}
2:{id: 563, style_id: 118, level: 3, name: "2nd Gup", type: "double", tip_enabled: 1, tip_sequential: 1,…}
3:{id: 564, style_id: 118, level: 4, name: "3rd Gup", type: "solid", tip_enabled: 1, tip_sequential: 1,…}
4:{id: 565, style_id: 118, level: 5, name: "4th Gup", type: "solid", tip_enabled: 1, tip_sequential: 0,…}
5:{id: 917, style_id: 118, level: 6, name: "5th Gup", type: "solid", tip_enabled: 0, tip_sequential: 1,…}
school_id:null
updated_at:"2017-05-22 15:34:32"
```

[image]

I want to get the ranks id and name

Comment: That response doesn't look right... doesn't look like valid JSON. Are you sure that's what the response actually is?

Comment: yes it is. I will provide a screenshots

Comment: Novice, you pasted the "parsed value" so your pasted text doesn't look like json.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly

Comment: fetch the response and put it to my select field. the value of rank id and name. like id 561 name 1st dan.

Comment: Looks like you're getting a response that's an array of length 1.  You'd probably need to do something like `data[0].ranks`. If i were you, I'd put the `data` into a global var so it's available to probe with test commands from the console (until I figured out the right syntax.  Then, not a global.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
function fetch(select){
    if ($(select).val() !== null) {
        var rank= $("#rank");
        $.getJSON('{{route("json_style_rank")}}', {id: $(select).val()}, function(data) {
            $("#rank option").remove();
            //Get and loop over only first element of the response array
            $.each(data[0].ranks, function(){
                rank.append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
            });
            rank.select2().val(null).trigger('change');
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**:
To iterate over all the elements in the response array, you'll need one more `$.each` loop

```
$.each(data, function(){
    //Get and loop over only first element of the response array
    $.each(this.ranks, function(){
        rank.append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
    });
});
```

Comment: what if it has more than 1 object inside an array? how can I dynamically fetch the other value?  
0:{id: 29} 1:{id: 29}  2::{id: 29}  .... and soon.

Comment: Can you please give an example of such type of data?

Comment: like $.each(data[0] ----> what if there is another like data[1] data[2] I mean how can i dyanamicaly assign and index in data[n]

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out

Comment: Thank you sir @sandesh Gupta for the help.